# How do i cancel notification using mBuilder.addAction

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I want to **add cancel buttons** on notification.
On **click** of that button i want to remove my notification from notification bar.
Is there any way to do that or i am doing it in a wrong way.

```
 noti=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      mBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.and);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Downloading");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Downloading in progress");
        mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.and,"cancil",);
```

Comment: what have you tried let us know?

Comment: what pending intent should i pass after cancel

Comment: you want custom notification right? with a cancel button

Comment: yes, i just want to remove my notification from notification bar after click of that cancel button which is right below that notification.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

 //Button as addAction is deprecated use this one.
NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Cancel", pendingIntent).build();

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentText("Back to Application ?")
        .setContentTitle("Amazing news")
        .addAction(action) //add buton
        .build();

//Send notification
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
        this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```